# is `freeaddrinfo` safe/needed when `getaddrinfo` return non-zero on linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, dns, network-programming, getaddrinfo

what might the `**res` be if `getaddrinfo` return non-zero ?

**Is it safe**, to call `freeaddrinfo`, with **all possible values** might be given by `getaddrinfo` ?(exp. `null`)

**Is it needed**, to call `freeaddrinfo`, if `getaddrinfo` return non-zero ?

Or, is there a possibility, that `getaddrinfo` might allocate memory for result, and did not free it, when there are errors ?

And, will there be differences, among different implementations of libc, and OS kernel ?

Comment: You should probably show your proposed code to provide more context. Did you initialize `res` to `NULL`? Or is it garbage? If you initialized it, you should be safe to call `freeaddrinfo` even if `getaddrinfo` fails.

Comment: Setting *res to 0 is a good idea, but I wonder is it really needed to call freeaddrinfo if it failed

Answer (score 1):

Do not use freeaddrinfo() when getaddrinfo() has failed, this will generate a Segmentation Fault on most linux system.

Windows seems to be ok with that but this is bad practice.